# Hasura event trigger with incorrect bigint value

Tags: postgresql, events, hasura

I'm using Hasura's events to trigger side effects of a database row update. The hook that I've set up uses the id of the row that is updated but the id that is being sent in the `req.body.event.data.new` is incorrect.

The row's id is a big int, e.g. "50755254975729665" but is being passed in the event as a modified version of that id "50755254975729660".

I previously had to update the hasura service with "HASURA_GRAPHQL_STRINGIFY_NUMERIC_TYPES" so I could see the correct big int values in the GUI. Is there a similar environment variable I need to set to ensure the correct value is passed in events?

Comment: I am not aware of a similar flag for events, so I assume, that this is a bug. I think the best would be to fire an issue on https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine

Comment: Looks like the Hasura team will be working on it. I'll post the solution here once there's an update.

https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3697